# Exporting to visio in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visio

I have datatable with the employee heirarchy and when the user clicks on a button. A .vsd file will be downloaded with the data and diagrams displaying it??
I don't know how to implement this exactly so I'm open to suggestions.
If there is any code samples, please write it or mention the link.
I'm working on Asp.net mvc project.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff758690(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Are you saying to want the generate a Visio compatible representation of some hierarchical data stored in a `Datatable`?

Comment: yes exactly. But regarding what the data is. I want some sample code how to generate visio (export to visio) like export to pdf.